# how to include spaces in a text output in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to print

```
String:   fsdfsdf   sdf
Double: 2.3534534534523453E11
Int: 2147483647
```

Using java if i give the input as

```
2147483647
235345345345.234534
  fsdfsdf   sdf
```

but my output is

```
String: fsdfsdf   sdf
Double: 2.3534534534523453E11
Int: 2147483647
```

help me how can i include those spaces at the front in the output
my code:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        String s = scan.next();
        String sn = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: " + s + sn);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not see a problem here

Answer (score 1):

A `Scanner` uses whitespace to break input into tokens by default. And `Scanner.next()` returns the next found token, which in your case is "fsdfsdf".

Simply set a different delimiter, e.g. the line separator:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        scan.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        String s = scan.next();
        String sn = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: " + s + sn);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
String:   fsdfsdf   sdf
Double: 2.3534534534523453E11
Int: 2147483647
```

(note that this also makes `String sn = scan.nextLine();` redundant, because `next()` will already give you "  fsdfsdf   sdf")

Comment: So why can't he just parse the numbers?and then read the two lines?

Comment: still not getting it prints a error

Comment: you may use an array list to read input and parse data according to their request  String[] in = new String[3]  like Double.parseDouble(in[1]) etc.